# How to connect SelectedIndex in Combobox to List Connection string?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, connection

How to connect SelectedIndex in Combobox to List Connection string?

here is the implementaion of the view:

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="cboxGDAservers" SelectionChanged="cboxGDAservers_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="GDA02"/> //If I select this I want it to connect to DKCDCVDCP30
    <ComboBoxItem Content="GDA03"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="GDA04"/>
</ComboBox>
```

**Code behind**

```
private async void GDAworkers(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<GDAWorkerDataModel> GDAWorkersConsolidated = new List<GDAWorkerDataModel>();
  string[] GDAServerList = new string[] { "DKCDCVDCP30", "DKCDCVDCP31", "DKCDCVDCP32" ...
     try
      {
       foreach (var GDAServer in GDAServerList)
         {
          List<GDAWorkerDataModel> GDAWorkers = new List<GDAWorkerDataModel>();
          var Result = GDAAcquisitionViewModel.GetWorkers(GDAServer);
          return Result;
          GDAWorkersConsolidated.AddRange(GDAWorkers);
         }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
         {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
         }
       DGGDAWorker.ItemsSource = GDAWorkersConsolidated;
      PbarGDAWorker.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

Comment: Set `SelectedValuePath="Content"` on the ComboBox and query `cboxGDAservers.SelectedValue` in your SelectionChanged handler.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged

Comment: When you ask a question, try to formulate it correctly.
And the code you show should be minimal but WORKING.
Let's say how to understand the "return Result" in the "void" method?
Or, in XAML, you have the cboxGDAservers_SelectionChanged method specified and you are showing the code for the GDAworkers.
The ComboxBox is named "cboxGDAservers", but there is no reference to that name in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use binding to a property and than in the main method that uses the selected item you can use the changed value:

the Xaml

```
<ComboBox Name="cboxGDAservers"
          SelectedValuePath="Content"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ConnectionString}">
<ComboBoxItem Content="GDA02"/> //If I select this I want it to connect to DKCDCVDCP30
<ComboBoxItem Content="GDA03"/>
<ComboBoxItem Content="GDA04"/>
```

and in the code behind -> the view model you need to add a string property:

```
 public MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     private string _connectionString;
     public string ConnectionString
     {
        get { return _connectionString; }
        set
        {
            if (_connectionString== value) return;
            _connectionString= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ConnectionString");
        }
     }
     // here you can use the workers with selected value from the added property

   }
```

Comment: You also need to show how the view model is connected to the view.